# How to control animation speed?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation

I'm moving an image and then expanding the image. The problem is my image is moving way to fast. Is there a way to to allow 2 animations to run and to control the speed? Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)pushmove {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
    square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200,-300);
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(8,8);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

It's possible and fairly straightforward. The key thing is that`CAAnimation`implements the`CAMediaTiming`protocol. So either on the`CAAnimation`or`CAAnimationGroup`you can set the speed as follows:

```
myAnimationGroup.speed = 2;
```

So if duration is`4`, your group will execute in`2`seconds.

Some of Apple's videos are very helpful on this subject. WWDC 2010 Session 424 covers`CAMediaTiming`and it's uses. Checkout 46:30 seconds into the video.

Here's the link:
[WWDC 2010 Sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/)